# Did Google Finance API Go Away or Just Change Signature?

Tags: programming, market-data, historical-data, google

I have been using Google finance for many months to pull intraday and daily data. Today I tried to use it and got redirected. For example, the following URIs returned text data that could be parsed:

Intraday (1-minute interval):
`http://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?auto=1&q=AAPL&i=60&p=4d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v`

Daily:
`http://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?auto=1&q=AAPL&i=86400&p=2d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v`

Does anyone know if the URI and query format has changed or has it just gone away as the old version of the finance page was deprecated?

Comment: I also noticed since yesterday that the finance API now redirects to the main finance website. Sometimes it works but most of the time it just returns a redirection. I guess Google just stopped their API without notice... If anyone finds a way to access all the data like before i'm very interested.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a service provider availability test

Comment: For future reference, seems my question should have gone here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

These URLs should not have changed. Note, however, that you may sometimes get one of these `I'm not a robot` captchas.

So if you are loading the returned data programmatically (say, via Python), then you may run into issues when Google randomly slips in one of these captchas.

Comment: You are correct. The URIs are working again. Perhaps the endpoints were down for a period of time when I was trying to use them.

Comment: Now it is not working. Back to same problem with the redirect.